# "Мой дядя самых честных правил" — о каких правилах говорит Пушкин в "Евгении Онегине"?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, литература, литературоведение

Недавно в статье прочитала такой текст:

*Вспомним начальные строки “Евгения Онегина”: “**Мой дядя самых честных правил** ”. Чтобы правильно понять размышления героя романа, словарных значений его слов недостаточно (Мой + дядя + самых + честных + правил ведёт к искажению содержания). При таком восприятии не избежать ошибки. Особенно это касается тех, кто плохо знаком с ситуацией в культурной жизни общества того времени, когда поэт приступил к работе над романом. Но многие его читатели легко поняли героя... так как связали его речь с опубликованной накануне **басней И.А. Крылова “Осёл был самых честных правил** ”. Эта синтагма из басни стала аллюзивным материалом, ключом, к пониманию размышлений героя романа, который **вовсе не хвалит дядю, а осуждает***. http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/38304/39-Filatova.pdf?sequence=1

Но вроде бы не все литературоведы согласны с тем, что текст Пушкина связан с басней Крылова.

Да и вообще начало романа мне совершенно непонятно – **все фразы кажутся загадочными.** Осуждает герой дядю или хвалит, да и за что? Какое именно правило названо честным? Что означает противопоставление, выраженное союзом НО? Толкование выражения  "уважать себя заставил" тоже вызывает сомнение.

Нельзя ли как-нибудь  пересказать содержание поближе к современному пониманию.

Спасибо.

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://youtu.be/Arco6P3ULQY) на 26:00, Михаил Казинник рассказывает свою версию и интересные детали. Но про "честные правила" там ответа в явном виде нет, его, видимо, в какой-нибудь анализе басни Крылова можно поискать.

Comment: Спасибо, Казинника послушала.  Артист он хороший, сюжеты хорошо закручивает. Даже если это пародия на сюжет, то пародия занимательная и полезная.

Comment: Он с одним "н" пишется. Умеет растолковать, почему старик жил "со своею" старухой и почему "Мёртвые души" - поэма. А здесь, возможно, не видит сложностей. В моем понимании, конкретные "честные правила" здесь - сдержать обещание, не обманув с завещанием в обмен на уход: ты мне, я - тебе.

Comment: Что значит "в обмен на уход"?  Уход, вероятно,  просто подразумевался, если хочешь получить наследство. Онегин едет к дядюшке,  представляя свои скучные обязанности, а дядюшка делает ему сюрприз - уже уже умер.  Тогда о чем говорится в первой строфе, что значит "лучше выдумать не мог, его пример другим наука"? Нет, пока не понимаю, надо литературоведа читать.

Comment: А где там о сюрпризе? "Уважать себя заставил" и "приказал долго жить" - разве это одно и то же?

Answer (score 2):

Приведу более авторитетное, как мне кажется, объяснение. Сначала замечу, что относительно "Но" Михаил Казиник (см. комментарий **tum_** к вопросу) говорит вполне разумно — в полном соответствии с сюжетом романа. Однако, Ю.М. Лотман в своих фундаментальных комментариях к ЕО критиковал "ослиную" версию, что-то упрощал до нагромождения распространённых в те времена фразеологизмов, а что-то другое, наоборот, усложнял:

> I, 1 - Мой дядя самых честных правил... — Первая строфа романа,
> представляющая прямую речь героя, вводит читателя непосредственно в
> середину действия, которое получает, однако, продолжение лишь в конце
> главы с LII по LIV строфу. В.М. Жирмунский считал одним из
> отличительных признаков "байронической" поэмы то, что "внезапный зачин
> вводит нас ех abrupto (т. е. "вдруг". — Ю.Л.) в середину действия
> <...>, а все предварительные условия драматического конфликта (т. н.
> "Vorgeschichte") сообщаются задним числом, как объяснение уже
> совершившихся перед нами событий" (Жирмунский В. Байрон и Пушкин. Л.,
> 1977, С. 55). Однако подчеркнуто-бытовой и сатирический характер
> эпизода ЕО придавал "байроническому" зачину пародийный характер. С
> этим же связано и нагнетание в первой строфе фразеологизмов
> разговорной речи, резко ощущаемых, благодаря начальной позиции и
> контрасту с элегическим эпиграфом: "самых честных правил", "не в шутку
> занемог", "лучше выдумать не мог", "пример другим наука".
>
> Строфа завершается шокирующим включением в текст ругательства.
> Упоминание "черта" вносит в речь героя "щегольской" оттенок, являясь
> калькой с французского "Que diable t'empoite". В народной речи той
> поры слово "черт" обязательно заменялось эвфемизмами "прах тя побери",
> "провал тя побери". Чертыхание — постоянный признак речевой маски
> щеголя в сатирической литературе XVIII в. (ср. из письма Щеголихи:
> "...ты это славно прокричал — чорт меня возьми!" — Сатирические
> журналы Н.И. Новикова. М.-Л., 1951, С. 312). Восклицание, смысловая
> значимость которого подчеркнута помещением его в заключительный стих
> строфы, имеет еще одно значение: в момент работы над началом романа
> Пушкин был увлечен романом Ч.Р. Метьюрина "Мельмот-скиталец". Роман
> начинается тем, что молодой Джон Мельмот отправляется "к умирающему
> дяде, средоточию всех его надежд на независимое положение в свете"
> (Метьюрин Ч.Р. Мельмот-скиталец. Л., 1976, С. 7), а кончается тем, что
> Скитальца уносит дьявол. Восклицание Онегина вносит, с одной стороны,
> в сюжетное начало романа элемент пародии, а с другой — раскрывает
> параллель Онегин — Мельмот как элемент самооценки героя, на которую
> автор смотрит иронически.
>
> Встречающееся в комментариях к ЕО утверждение, что выражение "самых
> честных правил" — цитата из басни Крылова "Осел и мужик" ("Осел был
> самых честных правил"), не представляется убедительным. Крылов
> использует не какое-либо редкое речение, а живой фразеологизм устной
> речи той поры (ср.: "он набожных был правил..." в басне "Кот и
> повар"). Крылов мог быть для П в данном случае лишь образцом обращения
> к устной, живой речи. Современники вряд ли воспринимали это как
> литературную цитату.

Comment: Спасибо и вам, но здесь мне придется разбираться. Но интерес к началу романа явно возрос, я-то рассчитывала на несложный пересказ содержания, а здесь всё действительно загадочно. Может,  и еще кто-нибудь ответит, совсем интересно будет.

Comment: Я добавлю в копилку ещё этот [фрагмент перевода комментариев Набокова к своему переводу "ЕО" на английский](https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=268424&p=5). Там есть интересное замечание: "Первые пять строк главы Первой мучительно темны. Я утверждаю, что это было сознательно сделано нашим поэтом, чтобы начать повествование туманно, а затем постепенно освободиться от первоначальной туманности." :)

Comment: Только что попалась ["статья"](https://zen.yandex.ru/media/studinter/taina-pervyh-3h-strok-evgeniia-onegina-5f0c37330807036ad900321b) на Яндекс.Дзен на эту же тему, от 14 июля. Некий Дзен-канал STUDINTER объясняет всё, так сказать, на пальцах, попутно упрекая Пушкина в неудачной рифме :) У канала свыше 5-ти тысяч подписчиков. Комментарии тоже весьма любопытны: половина комментаторов "просвещает" читателей, что, мол, "уважать себя заставил" = "умер", и что, мол, "стыдно этого не знать". Но есть и несколько дельных комментариев.

Answer (score 2):

Изложу как понимаю сам эти строки. Мне удивительны опровергающие одно другое исследования этого фрагмента текста, в которых пытаются придать простым словам путаные смыслы.

Дядя мой - человек честных правил в том смысле, что в завещании не обделит, но взамен требует услугу - поухаживать напоследок. Тем самым он требует проявить к себе уважение (что ж, разумно с его стороны - и другим в таком положении стоит взять его подход на вооружение, "поучиться"), и лирическому герою предстоят неприятные тяготы в ожидании конца. От этого ему досадно, а скорый конец дяди (буквально, забирание его чертом) желанен из-за наследства, глубоких же родственных чувств у него нет (они мало общались и т .п.).

Видимо, трудности в понимании создают некоторые версии толкования фразы "уважать себя заставил" (будто это когда-то означало "умер"), но это противоречит последовательности изложения событий в тексте и другими исследователями категорически отвергается, например, в этой статье:
https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/yazyk-pushkina-leksikograficheskie-etyudy-ii-on-uvazhat-sebya-zastavil/pdf

Comment: Alex_ander, спасибо за статью, внимательно прочитала её. Времени потрачено немало, но я ничуть не жалею, так как узнала много нового для себя. Чуть позже напишу подробно о статье и о своем окончательном (на данном этапе) мнении по этой теме.

Answer (score 1):

**О начале романа А.С. Пушкина "Евгений Онегин"** (по материалам статьи из ответа Alex_ander)

**Версия 1. Бессердечный племянник**

По мнению литературоведа-пушкиниста  В.С. Непомнящего, «дядя серьезно заболел и тем самым вызвал одобрение и уважение циничного племянника».

Начинается статья **с детективной истории,** где в главной роли выступает **точка с запятой.** Ее Непомнящий обнаружил  в самом первом издании романа: «Мой дядя самыхъ честныхъ правилъ, Когда не въ шутку занемог;»  Тогда две первые строки – это **одно предложение.**

И всё сразу встает на свои места, **версия выглядит примерно так.** Онегин едет в деревню после известия о серьезной болезни дяди (при этом о его смерти он еще не знает) и рассуждает вот о чем.

Дядя уже в летах, пожил в свое удовольствие и теперь очень правильно  и «честно» поступил, решив закончить свой жизненный путь. Это лучшее, что он мог сделать,  и поэтому достоин уважения. Все на его месте должны поступать так. Конечно, не хочется ехать, чтобы «подушки поправлять», но что делать – надо!

Всё очень логично,  и  осёл из басни Крылова здесь ни при чем: «самых честных правил»  –  обычный оборот речи.

**Версия 2. Нет, он не циник, просто не хочет притворяться и соблюдать чуждые ему формальности**

Но тут обнаруживается,  что **точка с запятой**  в других прижизненных изданиях отсутствует,  там стоит запятая. Значит, между двумя первыми строками **нет смыслового единства**.

Кроме того, глагол ***уважать*** в пушкинское время был **многозначным**:  уважать – это признавать важность, учитывать и считаться с чем-то; также быть внимательным, то есть проявлять знаки внимания. Можно было даже уважать людей, которые по современным понятиям этого никак не заслуживают, например: «Уважайте глупцов, ибо должно стараться иметь больше голосов на своей стороне».

**Что же хотел дядя от Онегина?** Он лишь попросил наследника приехать, чтобы проститься с ним.  Дядю нельзя считать благодетелем Онегина, поскольку Евгений был единственным законным наследником его имения, а  играть роль огорченного и нежного родственника обязывали пушкинского героя не деньги, а  чувство деликатности и человечности (по Белинскому).

**Тогда вторая версия выглядит так.** Дядя следует вековым традициям и условностям (честным правилам) и считает, что племяннику положено проститься с ним, то есть оказать ему внимание (уважение). А Онегин чужд таких формальностей, иронизирует над ними. И еще он злится на дядю (заставил, лучше выдумать не мог), потому что придется притворяться, а это не в его правилах – унижать себя притворством.  Мог бы отказаться, но всё-таки едет, он чувствует себя морально обязанным выполнить просьбу дяди.

Оценить поведение Онегина можно **по цитате** из романа «Не в первый раз он тут явил Души прямое благородство», хотя она и относится к другому эпизоду.

**А как же осел, который был «честных правил»?**  Вероятно, у Пушкина он всё-таки как-то обыгрывается. Дядя Онегина тоже стремится ревностно  следовать правилам, хотя это  не всегда это имеет положительный эффект.

**А вывод** можно сделать такой. Нет, не зря литературоведы спорят о начале пушкинского романа, **не так-то просто** выбрать правильную версию.

**Примечание**

А про **точку с запятой** забыли?  Всё дело в том, что  точка с запятой  раньше обозначала **длительность паузы** (сейчас на ее месте можно бы поставить интонационное тире).

Старая русская пунктуация отличалась гораздо больше «паузной нагруженностью» и была «гораздо более чувствительна к интонационно-мелодической стороне речи, чем современная. Запятая показывала «кратчайшую остановку голоса», точка с запятой – «остановку, вдвое долѣе запятой», двоеточие – «втрое долѣе запятой», точка – «должайшую остановку, вчетверо противъ запятой».

Вот о чем не надо забывать составителям современных правил – о чувствительности знаков препинания к мелодической стороне русской речи.

Comment: играть роль огорченного и нежного родственника обязывали пушкинского героя не деньги, а чувство деликатности и человечности. Дело в том, что Онегин эгоист, просто он еще об этом не знает, потому что эгоизм еще не придумали. Он слишком идеализирует свой образ, ведь он ведет себя по норме, так что не может критически рассмотреть самого себя. А вот Пушкин может абстрагироваться от своего эго, через Онегина. Кстати. Он+его+ин. Он рожденный от эго, Пушкина, само собой, точнее не Онегин эгоист, а Онегин - персонификация эгоизма Пушкина, любви и деликатности к собственной персоне.

Comment: Татьяна - это персонификация женского конфликтного эгоизма, выраженного также в рациональном поведении героини, в конфликте рацио и души. Тать - тайно ворованное, намеренно скрытое, яна - это с одной стороны божественная милость, с другой стороны двуликий Янус.

Comment: Я читала книгу о художественном пространстве в романе Пушкина (она для студентов-филологов), там много чего есть.  Становится понятным,  что сюжет художественного романа — это лишь повод, чтобы рассказать о многом.  И вот ваши  мысли – это нечто особенное. Надо будет перечитать книгу и сравнить разные точки зрения.

Comment: Я думаю да, роман для Пушкина, его сюжет - это просто условная форма его творчества. И это опять же к сюжету и фабуле, вы же знаете, чем отличается сюжет от фабулы?

Answer (score 1):

Осёл в басне Крылова — рьяный служака, обделённый умом. Типичный образ того времени. Как можно спорить, что такая длинная цитата, взятая у Крылова, на самом деле взята не у Крылова, лично я не понимаю.

«Уважать себя заставил» — дал дуба, склеил тапки, отбросил коньки, приказал долго жить. Услышав любую из этих фраз, каждый поймёт, что речь, без сомнения, идёт о смерти. То же самое касается и «уважать себя заставил», просто она вышла из обихода.

Поэтому следующий «перевод» на современный русский, который мне попадался, должен быть понятен:

*Мой дядя — недалёк, но честен —

Когда не в шутку занемог,

Отдал концы без долгих песен,

И лучше б выдумать не мог.*

«Герой» дядю не осуждает и не хвалит, он бравирует цинизмом. С этого начинается раскрытие его образа.

P.S. Вот то же самое, но прозой: «Хорошо, что мой осёл-дядюшка, словив рак, быстренько скончался, не заставив меня лицемерно ему сочувствовать ради наследства».

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение, интересно.

Answer (score 1):

Следование правилам, это знаете, как, например, "честные" отношения:

Например, некий мч предлагает встречаться некой девушке. Но он заранее предупреждает, что это просто секс и ничего более и что он может влюбиться в другую, но тогда обязательно поставит в известность текущую пассию, но это будет наверняка, он поступит "правдиво" и "честно".

То есть это откровенно? Вроде да. Правдиво? Ну вроде да, ведь такой был уговор.

Хотя, я забегаю вперед, это уже следующий этап, когда понятия чести, высокой традиции уже совсем разрушено.

А то, что описано в Онегине, когда поведение все-таки содержало эталон чести, когда форма еще соответствовала некому положительному примеру. То есть это еще не цинизм, когда такое откровенное предательство идеалов с nothing personal, just a business, но уже неискренность.

И что любопытно, что Онегин рассказывая о дяде, говорит, да, я не могу обвинить дядю, в том, что он был не в праве требовать уважения к себе, но, какой же он всё-таки коварный гад, потому что принуждает своим требованием следования моральному эталону Онегина быть не искренним:

*Какое низкое коварство

Полуживого забавлять,

Ему подушки поправлять,

Печально подносить лекарство,

Вздыхать и думать про себя:

Когда же чёрт возьмет тебя!*

То есть, конечно, этот отрывок не про дядю, а про отношение Онегина и его собственное оправдание своего мысленного греха. Онегин ведь такой жук, дело не в том, что его как-то изобличает или нет театр общества, нет, а в его отношении к самому себе. Это его исповедь, от откровенен, виден его ход мыслей, и дело даже не то, как плохо или хорошо он думает, а как он находит себе оправдания в попытках снять с себя вину за то, что он был вынужден претворяться, играть "печаль", притворствовать и желать скорейшей смерти своему, по сути, благодетелю.

Онегин не может с одной стороны признаться, а с другой стороны не может себе простить, что прогнулся, перед "полуживым". То есть можно бояться и слушаться живого "дядю", можно восхвалять мертвого, а дядя хитро заставил уважать себя как мёртвого, идеального, но при жизни - это же трюк? Но вот это полу- создает кучу парадоксов и вызывает массу дискомфортных состояний, и этот дискомфорт незавершенности довлеет над "молодым повесой":

*дядя самых честных правил,

Когда не в шутку занемог,

Он уважать себя заставил

И лучше выдумать не мог.

Его пример другим наука;*

Дядя вроде честный, но шутник, хитрец ведь, но тут ему нельзя сказать, что он шутит, и он "заставляет" себя уважать тем, что нельзя отшутиться, хотя это же шутка, он выдумал свою болезнь и будущую смерть так ловко, смерти же нет - Онегин не может поверить, в смерть, в то, что когда-то шутки кончатся, он же еще так молод.

Но дело же не в дяде, дело в том, что это мысли Онегина, и Пушкина. Откровение воспоминаний Пушкина устами Онегина:

Онегин, добрый мой приятель,
Родился на брегах Невы,
Где, может быть, родились вы
Или блистали, мой читатель;
Там некогда гулял и я:
Но вреден север для меня.

Короче, не спешите обвинять дядю, как это делает Онегин, и не спешите линчевать Онегина, как лицемера, а просто присмотритесь к себе, всегда ли вы искренни или тоже доказываете себе, что где-то да, пришлось прогнуться, потому что обманули, хитрецы.

Comment: Спасибо!! Ну очень интересно!  Жаль, что у нас не часто анализирую классику.  У вас к этому просто талант!